# Get the date when a field was first changed to its current value

Tags: sql, mysql, subquery

It's a fairly awkward thing to put into words, but I want the row when the item first switched to a tariff/customer.
If an item switches customer, then the date of the switch should be returned, regardless of the difference in tariff. If an item switches projects, the date returned must not change, unless the tariff of the new project is not the same as the old one.

Not quite sure how I can make it clearer, but I'm open to suggestions.

My query looks like this:

```
SET @id = 1;
SELECT DISTINCT
    ip.ItemID,
    ip.ProjectID,
    p.TariffID,
    p.CustomerID,
    cs.Date
FROM item_project ip
LEFT JOIN item_project ip1
    ON ip.ItemID = ip1.ItemID
    AND ip.Date < ip1.Date
LEFT JOIN project p
    ON ip.ProjectID = p.ProjectID
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        ip.ItemID,
        ip.Date
    FROM item_project ip
    LEFT JOIN item_project ip1
        ON ip.ProjectID = ip1.ProjectID
        AND ip.Date > ip1.Date
    LEFT JOIN project p
        ON ip.ProjectID = p.ProjectID
    WHERE ip.ItemID = @id
        AND ip1.ItemID IS NULL
        AND p.CustomerID = (
            SELECT p.CustomerID
            FROM project p
            LEFT JOIN item_project ip
                ON p.ProjectID = ip.ProjectID
            LEFT JOIN item_project ip1
                ON ip.ItemID = ip1.ItemID
                AND ip.Date < ip1.Date
            WHERE ip.ItemID = @id
                AND ip1.ItemID IS NULL
            )
        AND p.TariffID = (
            SELECT p.TariffID
            FROM project p
            LEFT JOIN item_project ip
                ON p.ProjectID = ip.ProjectID
            LEFT JOIN item_project ip1
                ON ip.ItemID = ip1.ItemID
                AND ip.Date < ip1.Date
            WHERE ip.ItemID = @id
                AND ip1.ItemID IS NULL
            )
) AS cs
    ON ip.ItemID = cs.ItemID
WHERE ip.ItemID = @id
    AND ip1.ItemID IS NULL
```

which gives me

```
"ItemID","ProjectID","TariffID","CustomerID","Date"
"1","2","1","1","2010-11-10 00:00:00"
```

which is the wrong date

`SET @id=2` gives me:

```
"2","2","1","1",NULL
```

Which is correct, apart from the date

`SET @id=3` gives me:

```
"3","2","1","1",NULL
```

which is also correct, apart from the date.

Here's the database

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `item_project` (
  `ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `ItemID` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `ProjectID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Date` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `item_project` (`ID`, `ItemID`, `ProjectID`, `Date`) VALUES
    (1, '1', 1, '2010-11-05 00:00:00'),
    (2, '1', 2, '2010-11-10 00:00:00'),
    (3, '1', 3, '2010-11-20 00:00:00'),
    (4, '2', 2, '2010-11-21 00:00:00'),
    (5, '3', 4, '2010-11-21 00:00:00'),
    (6, '3', 2, '2010-11-22 00:00:00'),
    (7, '1', 2, '2010-11-23 00:00:00'),

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `project` (
  `ProjectID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `Name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `TariffID` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `CustomerID` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`ProjectID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `project` (`ProjectID`, `Name`, `TariffID`, `CustomerID`) VALUES
    (1, 'Test', '2', '1'),
    (2, 'Another test', '1', '1'),
    (3, 'Project1', '1', '1'),
    (4, 'Main project', '2', '2');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tariff` (
  `TariffID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `Tariff` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`TariffID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `tariff` (`TariffID`, `Tariff`) VALUES
    (1, 'Tariff 1'),
    (2, 'Tariff 2');
```

**Edit**: An item can go back to an old tariff or customer. In this case, the date shown should be the date when this happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My previous answer appeared to work with the new dataset too, but I think I understand the problem you're seeing. New proposed solution:
`SELECT i_general.ItemID, ProjectID, TariffID, CustomerID, the_date
FROM
(
    SELECT ip.ItemID, p.ProjectID, p.TariffID, p.CustomerID
    FROM item_project ip
    INNER JOIN project p ON ip.ProjectID = p.ProjectID
    INNER JOIN tariff t ON p.TariffID = t.TariffID
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT ip.ItemID, MAX(Date) AS max_date
        FROM item_project ip
        GROUP BY ip.ItemID
    ) ip_max ON ip_max.ItemID=ip.ItemID AND ip_max.max_date=ip.Date
) i_general
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT ItemID_1 AS ItemID, IF(MAX(Next_Change_Date) IS NULL, MIN(Date_1), MAX(Next_Change_Date)) AS the_date
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT ItemID_1, Date_1, MIN(Date_2) AS Next_Change_Date
        FROM
        (
            SELECT ip1.ItemID AS ItemID_1, ip1.Date AS Date_1, p1.TariffID AS TariffID_1, p1.CustomerID AS CustomerID_1
            FROM item_project ip1
            INNER JOIN project p1 ON ip1.ProjectID = p1.ProjectID
        ) ipp1
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT ip2.ItemID AS ItemID_2, ip2.Date AS Date_2, p2.TariffID AS TariffID_2, p2.CustomerID AS CustomerID_2
            FROM item_project ip2
            INNER JOIN project p2 ON ip2.ProjectID = p2.ProjectID
        ) ipp2 ON ItemID_1=ItemID_2 AND Date_1 < Date_2 AND ((TariffID_1!=TariffID_2 OR CustomerID_1!=CustomerID_2) AND Date_2 IS NOT NULL)
        GROUP BY ItemID_1, Date_1
    ) i_date_pair_info
    GROUP BY ItemID
) i_date_info ON i_date_info.ItemID = i_general.ItemID`

I think it provides the result you're looking for.

It's more robust in that one of the inner subqueries, `i_date_pair_info`, explicitly pairs each date with all subsequent *changes*, if there is one. The grouping then eliminates all but the soonest change.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't seem to get this to work with the real data. It works with the test data in the same scenario, so I'll give you the bounty at the end of the day if nobody else posts anything.

Comment: Bummer. If you can post new test data, I'll likely have time to take another run @ it. Thanks.

Comment: couldn't work anything out, but it turns out this would be much better off in a separate table, as we now apparently need historic data, too. Thanks for trying, though.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting situation. Here's what I came up with

```
SELECT i_general.ItemID, ProjectID, TariffID, CustomerID, the_date
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        ip.ItemID,
        p.ProjectID,
        p.TariffID,
        p.CustomerID
    FROM item_project ip
    INNER JOIN project p ON ip.ProjectID = p.ProjectID
    INNER JOIN tariff t ON p.TariffID = t.TariffID
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT 
            ip.ItemID, MAX(Date) AS max_date
        FROM item_project ip
        GROUP BY ip.ItemID
        ) ip_max ON ip_max.ItemID=ip.ItemID AND ip_max.max_date=ip.Date
) i_general
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT ip1.ItemID, IF(MIN(ip2.Date) IS NULL,MIN(ip1.Date),MIN(ip2.Date)) AS the_date  
    FROM item_project ip1
    INNER JOIN project p1 ON ip1.ProjectID = p1.ProjectID
    LEFT JOIN item_project ip2 ON ip1.ItemID=ip2.ItemID AND ip1.Date < ip2.Date  
    LEFT JOIN project p2 ON ip2.ProjectID = p2.ProjectID AND (p2.TariffID!=p1.TariffID OR p2.CustomerID!=p1.CustomerID)
    GROUP BY ip1.ItemID
    ) i_date_info ON i_date_info.ItemID = i_general.ItemID
```

Of course, you can insert in a few `WHERE ItemID = @id` as you see fit. The more there are on the inner queries, the better.

At any rate, it results in

```
+--------+-----------+----------+------------+---------------------+
| ItemID | ProjectID | TariffID | CustomerID | the_date            |
+--------+-----------+----------+------------+---------------------+
| 1      |         3 | 1        | 1          | 2010-11-10 00:00:00 |
| 2      |         2 | 1        | 1          | 2010-11-21 00:00:00 |
| 3      |         2 | 1        | 1          | 2010-11-22 00:00:00 |
+--------+-----------+----------+------------+---------------------+
```

So, it appears to work with the existing dataset. Lemme know if you can provide test data which it doesn't work against.

Comment: +1 This definitely works for the test data, but I seem to be having problems with the actual data. When I identify a pattern, I'll add some more test data, but that will have to wait until next week.

Comment: Updated the question. The data causing issues are the items which change from one customer/tariff, then back again.